# Android ListView scroll to select a item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I used the ListView with 4 items. when i click on the ListView items it shows the current  selected item. But i need to implement the Scroll Listener to select the items in ListView . When i scroll the ListView it shows current scrolled item ? Any one help me with this

Comment: Be clear in question. What exactly your expecting? scroll to select item in listview is the question but the explanation of the question is not the same.

Comment: You want scroll listener...??

Answer (score 1):

Override the `OnScrollListener` method in your `ListView` Listener

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {




        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() == totalItemCount - 1
                    ) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Last", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();


                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i used this code..  But i need to get the scrolled list item name.

Comment: This will give you the current scroll list item name:- list.get(listView.getCurrentItem())

Comment: i have used in my application so give me some time i will post you entire code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Implement `OnScrollListener` for your `ListView`

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) { 
    //firstvisible is your first visible item in the list
}
```